# Multi language with php .po (Poedit)

Tags: php, multilingual

I would like to ask some help about a multi language problem. I try to make a website which has options to change the language of the site. I use .po and .mo files and it is works.
Such as: If I change the language to FR then in the website where I use

```
<?php echo _("Contact");?>
```

then changeing the "Contact" to the equal in FR. It's ok, if I push the F5 or refress button then it keeps the choosed language.

The problem is:
If I modified the language and I click another menu bar, then after loaded the page forgot the previously choosed language (use the default language or the php echo contents in the source code - I don't know exectly)

In every pages (index.php, contact.php etc.) I included on the top the translate.php file. Looks like:

```
<?php include("translate.php"); ?>
<html>
<head>
```

The Translate.php file contains:

```
<?php
$locale = false; // initilize language parameter
if (isSet($_GET["locale"])) // check if getting locale value in query string
{
$locale = $_GET["locale"]; // add selected language in variable
}
else
{
 $locale = "hu_HU"; // set English US as default language
}
putenv("LANGUAGE=$locale");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
$domain = "messages";
bindtextdomain($domain, "locale");
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, "UTF-8");
textdomain($domain);
?>
```

So it is works if I have one page website (I think) but I have more pages on the site and if i click on it and loaded, then it forgot the previously choosed language (If i modified it). It is not too good to change the site language again and again on every page : /

Comment: Use a cookie to store the language choice. That's what they're for. (Better yet use Accept-Language: as default.) -- Also don't post screenshots of code. (Unless you want comics as answer.)

Comment: Thanks, I don't know to much about php programming.
I tried to solve it but unfortunately it's still wrong.
Such as, but I tried several variations: Can you help?
<?php
session_start();
if (isSet($_GET["locale"])) // check if getting locale value in query string
{
 $_SESSION['loca'] = $_GET['locale'];
 $lang = $_SESSION['loca'];
}
else
{
    $lang = "en_EN"; // set English US as default language
}

putenv("LANGUAGE = $lang");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang);
$domain = "messages";
bindtextdomain($domain, "locale");
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, "UTF-8");
textdomain($domain);
?>

Comment: And I have another question. This solution it will be good for me because it is use .po and .mo files and these are contains the sentences in any languages, Don't needed to make an ID with one word such as: <? echo WELCOME; ?> and then the welcam ID shows a long sentences,
With the .po I can use full sentences as ID, and the value will the same then th ID content such as:
<?php echo _("How it Works");?>
Then the ID in the .po file is: How it Works and the value is the same: How it Works

Comment: I have another solution with php, which is works, but then the sentences are in .php files with only one word ID-s such as:
<? echo WELCOME; ?> It is conatins maybe something like that: Welcome on my page.
But the question is:
It is problem for the SEO?
The search engines knows the content of the page or just see the ID such as: WELCOME ?
Thank you very much!

Comment: (1) Gettext/PO/MO usage is **not** related to how you store preferences in cookies or sessions. (2) And no, SEO is not a thing anymore. And search engines don't see PHP source anyway. (3) Questions shouldn't be diverted in comments.